# Mongo / Mongoose How can I remove all elements from array property from within a schema method?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My question is not about how generally to remove elements, I would just use update and $set array to []. I wonder how I can do it from within a schema method? For some reason I cannot remove anything and I dont understand what Im doing wrong. Thanks!

```
userSchema.methods.generatePasswordReset = function () {
    const user = this;
    user.resetPasswordToken = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');
    user.resetPasswordExpires = new Date(new Date().getTime() +  60 * 60000);
    if (user.resetPasswordAttemptTimes.length > 3) {
        user.resetPasswordAttemptTimes.splice(0) // doesnt change array
        user.resetPasswordAttemptTimes.length = 0 // also doesnt change
    }
    user.resetPasswordAttemptTimes.push(new Date().getTime())
};
```

Comment: try `user.resetPasswordAttemptTimes=[]`

Comment: splice definitely won't work as it returns a new mutated array.  setting the length to 0 arguably should work

Comment: assigning to it an empty array works but I would prefer not do it like that as it could mess up something in case I had something else referencing it. Setting length to 0 doesnt really work. when I log it after it does show me an empty array but then its not empty in my db so something is not working. Ps. I do call save method on user after calling generatePasswordReset.